# Crashing with a null pointer de-reference, why?

Tags: c++

I was reading [Moai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moai_%28game_development_platform%29) source code, and I became curious about why this should cause a crash (or not...)

I do not really understood that snippet.

In file A:

```
#define UNUSED(p) (( void )p)
```

In file B:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------//
/** @name   crash
    @text   Crashes Moai with a null pointer dereference.

    @out    nil
*/
int MOAISim::_crash ( lua_State* L ) {
    UNUSED(L);

    int *p = NULL;
    (*p) = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

I think part of what I was not understanding is what "deference" means. So if you put that in your answers it would be awesome.

Comment: The `UNUSED(L);` is just to suppress a warning about `L` being unused. The `return 0;` is just to keep the compiler happy since we told it the function returned an integer. (Of course, it doesn't actually return.)

Comment: I asked a very clear and technical question!

Comment: Also: the line that crashes is kinda obvious, I want to know how, or why, specifically... It is the (*p), the =, the 0, or the = 0, if it was = 1 it would work? And so on.

Comment: I guess I will have to refrain making maybe too newbie questions, since this results in a reputation pounding ¬¬

Next time I will ask it on irc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The crash is caused by the dereference of the null pointer:

```
(*p) = 0; // <--- Crash
```

Also as pointed out in the comments, the UNUSED macros is only there to suppress the "unused parameter" warning that most compilers will give.

It is usually also possible to prevent the warning by, simply, not specifying the variable name as follows:

```
int MOAISim::_crash ( lua_State* ) 
{
    int *p = NULL;
    (*p) = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

It's also worth bearing in mind that the above is not a guaranteed crash. On one of the 32-bit consoles de-referencing a null pointer actually resulted in the number "3". This did make null dereferences quite hard to find, but generally if you saw a 3 sitting around in a register you could hazard a good guess as to what had just gone wrong.

Dereferencing is essentially asking for the value stored at a given pointer. If the pointer is not valid (that is, pointing at a memory location that the process does not own) then it results in a crash. In Windows this is called an Access Violation (0xC0000005). Under Linux it's a Segmentation Violation, SIGSEGV.

[See also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference)

Comment: I like the "3" example, it's yet another nice example of how UB works - "it may crash, it may burn, or you may as well obtain `3`" :)

Answer (score 3):

The macro is replaced in the code, so for the compiler the function looks like this:

```
int MOAISim::_crash ( lua_State* L ) {
    (( void )L);

    int *p = NULL;
    (*p) = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

The `(( void )L)` line evaluates `L` and throw away the result. The crash, however, isn't from that line, instead it from the assignment to a `NULL` address at `(*p) = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *p = NULL;
(*p) = 0;
```

The second line is an undefined behaviour (dereferencing a nullptr pointer). The fact that is crashes the application on your platform is just one form of undefined behavior (in my opinion good, because you can catch bugs sooner).